# Jquery UI Datepicker with noweekend and calculating days ahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a form for employer's vacation, on which the person should choose the number of days of vacation and then select the date.
After the date is selected, the program should calculate the day of return.
This part is working perfectly with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        onClose: function () {
            var time = $('#selDias').val();
            var timeint = parseInt(time)
            var date2 = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + timeint)
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker("setDate", date2);
        }
    });
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
});
```

The problem is that I must forbid the user to choose the start date on a weekend, so I applied this:

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

Only when I do that, it stops calculating the return date.
I have tried everything but I cant figure out why.

Any lights?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it putting it all together:

```
$(".data").datepicker({

beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,

 onClose: function () {
            var time = $('#selDias').val();
            var timeint = parseInt(time)
            var date2 = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + timeint)




            $("#datepicker2").datepicker("setDate", date2);

        }
    });
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
```